# Django user.has_perm return false

Tags: python, django

I got some strange issue when user.has_perm always return true, even when permission is for sure in table.
Maybe someone got like this before?
Seams like issue only in last versions

Test show issue is below:

```
import django
import datetime
django.setup()


from django.contrib.auth.models import User

u=User.objects.get(pk=177)

print("version %s" % str(django.VERSION))
print("1: %s" %str(u.has_perm('not_show_tos')))


from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=u)

sorted_list_of_permissions = sorted(list(permissions))
print("2:%s " % str("not_show_tos" in sorted_list_of_permissions));
for i in sorted_list_of_permissions:
  print( str(i.codename))
  print("%s" %str(u.has_perm(i.codename)))
  print("\n")

p=Permission.objects.get(codename='not_show_tos');
print("4 %s " % str(p))
print("5 %s " % str(p in sorted_list_of_permissions))
print("6 %s " % str(u.has_perm(p)))
```

Test result

```
 python3 /tmp/test.py 
signals init done.
version (2, 0, 6, 'final', 0)
1: False
2:False 
not_show_tos
False


4 sessions | session | Not Show Tos Page 
5 True 
6 False
```

Answer (score 6):

The string you pass to has_perm should be in the format `"<app_label>.<permission.codename>"`. That is: `u.has_perm('sessions.not_show_tos')`

From the django docs:

> **has_perm(perm, obj=None)**
>
> Returns True if the user has the specified permission, where perm is in the format `"<app_label>.<permission.codename>"`. (see documentation on permissions). If the user is inactive, this method will always return False.
>
> If obj is passed in, this method won’t check for a permission for the model, but for this specific object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm

Comment: Thanks. This was confusing me as well. I did not realize that the codename had to be unique across the entire app and not just unique within the model object type.